# Extending DataTemplate programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My DataTemplate is declared like this :

**NOTE:** There is no key for the datatemplate, it is bound by type.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myType}">...
</DataTemplate>
```

And, it is bound to a TabControl

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myCollection}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}">
    <!-- TabStripPlacement="Left" -->
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Padding="2.5"
                       Text="{Binding Path=Caption}">
                    <!--<TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>-->
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Now, in the runtime, I want to load this DataTemplate and add context menus on the fly to the grid (which is part of the data template) in the codebehind. I tried this (**LoadContent**) but it does not seem to update the DataTemplate.

```
// get the datatemplate of the view (defined in the XAML)
var key = new DataTemplateKey(typeof (myType));
var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate) FindResource(key);

// load the root control (in this case the grid)
var grid = dataTemplate.LoadContent() as DataGrid;
```

This loads the grid and I can access the instance and properties successfully, but when I manipulate the properties, it is never reflected on the GUI.

Any alternative ways please?

Comment: Is it two way binding your after?

Comment: I did not get you. I just want to add context menus on the grid on the fly by loading the DataTemplate

Comment: No that won't work. And is usually not necessary. Do you want to fill your context menu dynamically? That can be easily achieved with an attached behavior.

Comment: So, how can I achieve that based on different types ? Any sample ?